# Duplicate line with offset if second field is filled

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry-generator, offset

I have a line layer with two fields `Field A` and `Field B` using the same value representation. Every object has a value in `Field A`, only some objects have a value in `Field B`.

I am looking to create a symbology that styles the line according to `Field A`.
But if a value in `Field B` is present, the line should offset to one side and a second line with the same offset to the other direction should be created, using the same symbology but referencing `Field B`.

I am now looking for a way to achieve this, hopefully via geometry generator.

This is my layer only styled by `Field A`:

[image]

This is my current workaround and close to what I want to achieve:

[image]

I currently duplicate my layer and use the same styling with offset via geometry generator and referencing `Field B`. So at the moment, my first layer is always using the line's real placement and the second layer is always set off. When there is a line with both values filled connecting to a line, where only one value is filled, it looks like this:

[image]

I would expect the upper line of the left part to be higher so the line on the right is connecting in the middle between the two lines on the left.

Comment: Does `Field_B` have the same value with `Field_A`?

Comment: It is not the same value per object, but using the same value range. So range is e.g. 1-7 for both fields, but object x has `Field_A`=3 and `Field_B`=6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need Geometry Generator per se, you can do it by creating a couple of extra symbol layers and using *Data Defined Overrides* to control their visibility:

[image]

###### Steps

1. Add 2 more symbol layers
2. One with a positive offset, one with a negative
3. Enter the following expressions in the *Enable symbol layer* Data Defined Override expression editor (one for each symbol layer).

The **original** symbol layer:

```
-- render feature only when one field is populated
case 
    when Field_A >= 0 and Field_B is null
    then true
    when Field_B >= 0 and Field_A is null
    then true
    else false
end
```

The **offset** symbol layer(s).

```
-- render feature only when both fields are populated
case 
    when Field_A >= 0 and Field_B >= 0
    then true
    else false
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If i understood you correctly, you can solve your problems with those steps.

Step 1

You need the create 2 different 'rule-based' symbology. like that...

[image]

Step 2

You need create 2 fields in attribute table for offset values.
( If you want you can do that automatically like "FiledB Value/2". But the field type must be string.)

[image]

Step 3

For Style 1 ( FieldB IS NULL ) line width comes from FieldA

[image]

Step 4

For Style 2 (FieldB IS NOT NULL) create 2 line symbology.

For the first one, width value comes from FieldA.

And Offset value comes from new fields (FieldB(C+))

[image]

For the second one, width value comes from FiledB.

And Offset value comes from new fields (FieldB(C-)).

[image]

I hope it will be helpfull for you.
[image]